# Postgresql update timestamp trigger in inherited table

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I used [this example](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/) and it worked well when all my tables were in *public* schema.

But trigger hasn't been working since I separated tables into different schemas and applied inheriting.

Here is example of my structure:

```
CREATE SCHEMA common;
CREATE SCHEMA video;

CREATE TABLE common.file (
    file_id    SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    url        VARCHAR(255)                         NOT NULL,
    mime_type  VARCHAR(31) DEFAULT ''               NOT NULL,
    size       INTEGER                              NOT NULL,
    modified   TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE video.file (
    width       INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    height      INTEGER                 NOT NULL,
    local_path  VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
)
INHERITS (common.file);

CREATE FUNCTION common.update_modified()
    RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER update_modified 
   BEFORE UPDATE ON common.file 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE common.update_modified();
```

When I do `UPDATE common.file ...` or `UPDATE video.file ...` field `common.file.modified` doesn't change itself. It seems trigger doesn't run, but I don't understand why.

What should I do to repair the behavior?

Comment: The trigger won't fire for updates on `video.file`, but it works fine for updates on `comon.file` for me: http://rextester.com/UVRSL27366

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the problem and wrote answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In described issue trigger is set only on `common.file`, so `UPDATE common.file ...` doesn't work if row inserted in `video.file`

Documentation says: *INSERT always inserts into exactly the table specified*

So trigger should be applied to both `common.file` and `video.file`.

```
-- Creating schemas and tables the same

-- Let function be in public scheme
CREATE FUNCTION update_modified()
    RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.modified = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER update_modified 
   BEFORE UPDATE ON common.file 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified();

CREATE TRIGGER update_modified 
   BEFORE UPDATE ON video.file 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified();
```

In that case when we update rows inserted either in `common.file` or in `video.file` corresponding trigger will call.